# How to pass a large number of vertices and colors in a fast and memory efficient way in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My UserFrame class stores colors and vertices as floats. On a per-frame basis I must retrieve these values in my game. I am storing several thousands of vertices in each instance of the class. My current approach is to pass these values as reference, which causes a memory leak because I am allocating these arrays outside my main scope. What is the correct way of passing these values to my main scope?

I would prefer not to return each array separately in 2 methods because I would need to loop twice (colors + vertices).

```
public class UserFrame
{
public float[] vertexX;

public float[] vertexY;

public float[] vertexZ;


public float [] r;

public float [] g;

public float [] b;



...


public void getVerticesAndColors(out Vector3[] outputVertexArray, out Color[] outputColorArray){

    outputVertexArray = new Vector3[ vertexX.Length];
    outputColorArray = new Color[ vertexX.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < vertexX.Length; i++) {

        outputVertexArray [i] = new Vector3 (vertexX [i], vertexY [i], vertexZ [i]);
        outputColorArray [i] = new Color (r [i], g [i], b [i]);
    }

}

}
```

EDIT:

I cannot store these variables as arrays of Vector3 or Colors because I am serializing the data, and this is not possible with these types.

Comment: fastest way is to not copy at all and just pass references, reuse the array. but that may not be always possible.

Answer (score 0):

At class initialization, I would convert those values directly into Color and Vector3 instances. I would then include a property or a static member to obtain them whenever necessary:

```
public class UserFrame
{
    public readonly Color[] Colors;
    public readonly Vector3[] Vertices;

    public UserFrame(float[] x, float[] y, float[] z, float[] r, float[] g, float[] b)
    {
        Int32 length = x.Length;

        m_Colors = new Color[length];
        m_Vertices = new Vector3[length];

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            Colors[i] = new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]);
            Vertices[i] = new Vector3(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tommaso, that was my first implementation. I forgot to mention that I am actually serializing the data and saving it to disk. I can't do this with the Vector3 and Color types.